# How can I add colour to a .obj model in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, model, three.js, textures

I am creating a WebGL scene with Three.js and I have the next problem: I am trying to load a .obj model with Three.js, and I want to add a color (blue, for example), to that .obj model, instead of a mtl texture. I try to do this way:

```
// instantiate a loader
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

// load a resource
loader.load(
    // resource URL
    'model_path.obj',
    // Function when resource is loaded
    function ( object ) {
        scene.add( object );
    }
);
```

But I have the next error that says:

```
WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: bufferData: no data
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
[.CommandBufferContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_VALUE : glVertexAttribPointer: size GL_INVALID_VALUE
```

How could I correct the error, to load an obj model with blue color?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey the error seems the vertex points are not there with the file. OBJ file is the simple raw file with

v :::: vertex

vt :::: texture coordinate

vn :::: normal

usemtl ::: define the texture,ka(ambient),ks(specular) and kd(diffused)

try to import your obj into the blender and then export with the triangulated face on like this:
[image]

actually if you don't do this the indices appear to you in face4 format like:

0/1/2/3 3/2/4/0 .... so on
after triangulation they appear like:

0/1/2 3/2/0 ...

So when you correct your *.obj you can load the file in three parser and add the material to the children.

Comment: can you make the fiddle or share the obj file i would like to check if not confidential..?? otherwise it will be hard to help

Comment: You can download the .obj file in this Dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mslv900i90ra445/Pawn.obj?dl=0

Comment: It works! Thanks! The model is loaded correctly. But now the problem that I have is that the textures isn't load. I mean, the method "var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('path') });" is deprecated. And when I use TextureLoader, the texture is not loaded and instead of that, a random color is loaded... Why does it happen?

Comment: For me the texture also load the texture coordinate are there
var loader = new THREE.ImageLoader( manager );
    loader.load( 'textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg', function ( image ) {

     texture.image = image;
     texture.needsUpdate = true;

    } );
if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {

       child.material.map = texture;
       
      }

I have no issue with texture too. One way you can see whether texture is correctly map is to load *.obj in blender and then do uv mapping. 
There are no issue with texture cordinates :) feel free to ask any doubts